# Font size with custom font

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

So I've got my image and even some text on it. I tried to load a font and it worked, but how could I select the font size? The code for the text I have is below.

```
imagestring($img, imageloadfont('dist/font.ttf'), 20, 20, 'Testing!', imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0));
```

Before, I could set the font size in the second attribute, but now I've got a remote font there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [imagettftext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) if you wish to write text to your image using a truetype font.

```
imagettftext ( 
   resource $im ,
   int $size ,
   int $angle ,
   int $x ,
   int $y ,
   int $col ,
   string $fontfile ,
   string $text 
)
```

This allows you to set the font size specifically. Should do for your purposes.

**Note**

Depending on your version of the GD library, you need to specify the font size in either pixels or points.

From the Docs:

> The font size. Depending on your version of GD, this should be specified as the pixel size (GD1) or point size (GD2).

Comment: What would I put for $angle? 0?

Comment: Yes, if you want to write horizontally, keep it at 0.

Comment: The color. Please refer to [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) under *Parameters*. Everything is explained there.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've managed to get it all working now. Thank you!